# HTML image tag src attribute

Tags: html, web, path

I want to include image, which is outside of php root dir.
I tried relative path but it doesn't show image.
It gives me 404 Not found error...
Can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test video</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<embed src="./1.mkv">???</embed>-->
    <img src="../fabicon.ico">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="./test/01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Source code: /Applications/MAMP/practice/CREATE_BOOKMARK
Image file: /Applications/MAMP/practice

Comment: Post your website link and the `path` where your image is located.

Comment: I can't start web server right now so I just uploaded source code and path

Answer (score 0):

ico is not a standard image format when it comes to browsers. Try converting to gif, png or jpg. If you don't know or have a software to convert images, here is a link where you can convert images in a couple of formats.

Image converter: https://www.coolutils.com/online/image-converter/

Hope this helps you out `<3`

Comment: I changed image as like this `<img src="../image.jpeg">`. However it shows same error

Comment: Did you converted the image as well? And your ending/format is wrong it's `jpg` and not `jpeg`

Comment: Maybe I think image tag can print jpeg format. Because when I moved it(image.jpeg) into same directory I can printed it.

Comment: I just tryed with file extension `<img src="../image.jpeg">` and it didn't work! So i renamed `.jpeg` to `.jpg` and it worked perfectly. Try to rename your `jpeg` to `jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how the directories that contain the image and the video are organized

The inproper use of relative path ./ and ../ may be the reason you get file not found.

Comment: I added path at question.